# Browse the whole database in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've created a simple site using PHP and MySQL and I'm trying to test if the database is receiving the entries as it should.

How within, PHPMyAdmin am I able to browse or download an Excel file to see every entry submitted?

Many Thanks

Comment: Just run PHPMyAdmin and browse it?

Comment: On the left, choose your database. The main area then shows all your tables within this database. There you find an icon to browser all entries. Also, there is a link to export the data.

Comment: There is a manual for PHPMyAdmin, just a tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have seen the phpmyadmin completely then its so easy to do that. After choose your database you will see on the top menu its have **Export** tab. on clicking that tab its displaying option you want to download file type..Thats it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Export tab on phpmyadmin and then export as excel file